# MySql select table option

Tags: mysql, insert, where-clause

I want to make a php form, with the option to select in which table, from the database to insert data. Something like a dropdown list, or anything else.. Can you help me?

Thank!

Comment: I used below query to get all table names in database

SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME, *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
ORDER BY TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME    ...

Comment: And this to insert data into a specific table:
$sql = "INSERT INTO $db_table(nume,email,telefon,companie,adresa,functie,website,colaborare,serviciu) values ('".mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_REQUEST['nume']))."','".mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_REQUEST['email']))."','".mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_REQUEST['telefon']))."','".mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_REQUEST['companie']))."','".mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_REQUEST['adresa']))."','".mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_REQUEST['functie']))."')";

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your PHP form why not have a simple select drop down like you have suggested with each drop-down option containing the table name that you want to insert into.

```
<select name='table-name'>
<option value='table1'>Table One</option>
<option value='table2'>Table Two</option>
</select>
```

Then simply get the value in PHP once your form has been posted using

`$_POST['table-name']` or `$_GET['table-name']` depending on your form method of course.

Bare in mind though that you know exacly what you are doing here as giving away vital information about your table structures can aid hackers in their dirty tricks.

You could always put the option values to identifier values instead of the actual table names and then using your PHP form handler map these to the correct table names. For example put your option values as simply 1 and 2 and then let your form handler convert these to the correct table names, only accepting specified values.

A couple of notes.

Always properly validate user input before connecting with your database using the user inputted information.

I hope you are using prepared statements for your database calls and binding the user inputted values to these, using PDO or similar for example